Understanding nvme over fabrics configuration and its persistence
I'm experimenting with understanding the NVMe protocol and for that creating a local NVMe over fabrics setup using a Linux VM, two VMs actually. These VMs are on the same network.
One of these VMs act as an NVMe target whereas the other acts as an initiator. I am then configuring the target as mentioned here. And everything goes as expected. I can use the initiator to "discover" the target subsystem. However this configuration doesn't persist across reboots. This was really surprising since on "regular" SCSI or SATA devices, the partition table is stored on the disk itself, be it MBR or EFI. so I obviously started looking and it led me into this rabbit hole of 'Software NVMe-oF Targets' vs 'Hardware NVMe-oF Targets'.
Apparently, 'nvmet' (nvme target) kernel module falls under the software category, so the configuration for namespaces and subsystems might not be automatically persisted across reboots unless explicitly saved and reapplied. The sysfs configurations (/sys/kernel/config/nvmet/) used for setting up 'soft' NVMe-oF targets on Linux are not automatically restored after a reboot.
This is different from a 'hardware NVMe-oF Target' where  the NVMe-oF target is implemented in firmware on a storage array or appliance, the namespace configuration would typically be persistent across reboots as it is managed by the hardware controller. Did I get it clear up until now? Am I missing something here?
I am specifically looking for a gist on:

Configuration differences between PCIe NVMe and NVMe over fabrics target on Linux
Understanding the various nuances that a 'typical' enterprise grade NVMe SSD uses for this
Any link or blog that you know of that will sufficiently cover details like these


This was really surprising since on "regular" SCSI or SATA devices, the partition table is stored on the disk itself, be it MBR or EFI. Why did you think that's related to the configurations of NVMe over TCP when the first sentence in the linked blog post tells you that it is like iSCSI? I don't know whether there's like a convenient daemon/manager in the nvme case that you can use to make the setup "persistent", but /sys is definitely volatile. You can certainly put the commands in a script and starts it with a systemd service (or perhaps in this case, even a udev rule is fine).

@TomYan I compared it with SCSI and SATA since it is also a block storage related protocol just like those. Which is why the whole concept of the configuration now persisting on the device itself baffles me.

I actually meant partition table part, which is not configuration data/states. sysfs (/sys) is not an interface for you to change (firmware) setting of the "backstore" drive, but one to talk to the kernel. In fact, the whole NVMe over TCP has nothing to do with the drive, except that it is "exposed" to the initiator such that commands sent via the "channel" would be "received" by it.

I don't know for certain if it has an "abstraction layer" like the case of iSCSI (in Linux) though, which allows the "backstore drive" to be something other than a SCSI drive, and I don't mean SATA drive which is "behind SATL" anyway, but like Logical Volume and so on.

And that the configuration is volatile isn't really about "software vs hardware", but just that kernel states are not "out of the box" persistent, just like while you can use ip(route2) to configure addresses and routes for network interfaces, the configuration is volatile, which is why you need a network manager (that runs in userspace and talks to the kernel), which allows you to specify and store states and policies in real files for it to read, or at least, something that repeats the desired ip commands on boot. sysfs files are like API calls presented as virtual files.
